# SQL Server = Creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HighScores 
(
    [User] varchar(255), 
    Score int, 
    DateAdded datetime
)

INSERT INTO dbo.HighScores 
VALUES ('Bob', 2500, '2 Jan 2013 13:13'),
       ('Jon', 1500, '2 Jan 2013 13:15'),
       ('Amy', 3500, '2 Jan 2013 13:18'),
       ('Joe', 1750, '2 Jan 2013 13:23'),
       ('Don',  500, '2 Jan 2013 13:33'),
       ('Ann',  800, '2 Jan 2013 14:03'),
       ('Mav', 1200, '2 Jan 2013 15:13'),
       ('Ken', 2600, '2 Jan 2013 15:32'),
       ('Ace', 2500, '2 Jan 2013 16:45'),
       ('Tom', 2700, '2 Jan 2013 16:59'),
       ('Leo',  300, '2 Jan 2013 17:33'),
       ('Jay', 1000, '2 Jan 2013 18:03'),
       ('Roy', 1200, '2 Jan 2013 18:13'),
       ('Vic', 2100, '2 Jan 2013 19:32'),
       ('Ted', 1800, '2 Jan 2013 20:45'),
       ('Pat', 1400, '2 Jan 2013 20:59')
```

create a stored procedure called `pr_GetHighScoreList`

We now need to add highscores to the table using pr_PutHighScoreList

•   You can only appear on the high score list once, and only your highest score must be stored.

•   We would also need to record the movement in the highscore table, when players move up in position.

Example:
pr_PutHighScoreList 'Ann', 2750

Will increase Ann's score from 800 to 2750 and we need to record that she moved from position 14 to 2 in a separate table.

•   Create the proc, and any other objects that may be required to store this.

This is what i did so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_PutHighScoreList]
(
  @name as nvarchar(20),
  @score as int
)

AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS
(SELECT * from [HighScores] 
 WHERE [User]=@name
 AND [Score]>@score)
UPDATE [HighScores]
   SET [User] = @name
      ,[Score] = @score
      ,[DateAdded] = getdate()
 WHERE [User]=@name
ELSE  
(SELECT * from [HighScores] 
 WHERE [User]!= @name)
INSERT INTO  [HighScores]
           ([User]
           ,[Score]
           ,[DateAdded])
     VALUES
           (@name
           ,@score
           ,getdate())

END
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  This looks like a homework assignment.  People generally happy to help but you should try yourself and show us where you are stuck.  Check out [the guidance on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `lag()` and `lead()` for Ann and her neighbors.  This is what a query looks like:

```
select *
from (select hs.*,
             row_number() over (order by score desc, [User]) as seqnum,
             lag([User]) over (order by score desc, [User]) as prev_user,
             lead([User]) over (order by score desc, [User]) as next_user
      from highscores hs
     ) hs
where seqnum <= 5 or
      'Ann' in ([User], prev_user, next_user)
order by seqnum;
```

You can adapt it for a stored procedure.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db8a35ef638702783d5e4744c77e8026) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will get you started

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = row_number() over (order by score desc,dateAdded desc)
 From  HighScores
)
Select * From cte where RN<=5
Union
Select A.*
 From  cte A
 Join (Select R1=RN-1,R2=RN+1 from cte where [User]='Ann' ) B on A.RN between B.R1 and B.R2
Order by RN
```

Results

[image]

Comment: I need help with additional question please

Comment: apologies, I was unaware.